# Django 1.5 and 1.6 compatibility issues – Exception Value: invalid syntax in views.py

Tags: django, django-users

I have the following code that worked great on my 1.5 version of Django

```
def login(request):
    c={}
    #c.update(csrf(request))
    loginform = LoginForm()
    c['loginform'] = loginform

    if request.method=='POST':

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            if user.is_staff:
                return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                return redirect('fullcalendar')
        else:
            msg = "Your account has been disabled!"
            c['msg'] = msg
            return render_to_response('login_disabled.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        msg = "Your username and password were incorrect. Please try again."
        c['msg'] = msg
        return render_to_response('login_incorrect.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But after upgrading to Django 1.6 i get the following error

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/rhombus/accounts/views.py" in login
  45.     return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  509.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  387.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  296.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  273.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  296.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  285.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  96.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 3) #which views is that.
```

All imports

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from accounts.forms import LoginForm
from django.template.context import RequestContext
```

It also produces another error in this line

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'mycal.views.fullcalendar' %}">Company</a>
```

I have a url and view that is named fullcalendar.

It worked fine in Django 1.5. What changed?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else changed? I ran the import statement both in 1.5 and in 1.6 and I didn't get any error. Try that yourself in a clean virtualenv.

Comment: well even if I remove it i get the same error...

Comment: can u share line no.3  of your views.py file.

Comment: I did its the import from django.contrib.auth

Comment: thanks ..hey please share line no2 and 4 also

Comment: It's like it won't recognize {% url %} template tag. If i remove it it works, if i add it it won't!!! But It did work before!!!

Comment: If i don't extend the login template from base.html it is rendered properly if i do it won't and shows the error described...:((...How can it break so much? I removed all url template tags and worked!!!!!! But I want them to be there!!!!

Comment: The syntax error was at another module, in an incomplete import statement...My mistake...everything works now!